# How to build and run C++ code with VSCode C++ plugin v1.6.0 on mac?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

While using v1.5.1, it works well. After updating the plugin to 1.6.0, the terminal shows nothing and has no output. How can I solve the problem?

```json
// launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Return to 1.5.1 can solve the problem, but I want to use it with 1.6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.